# Time complexity of a recursive function when it does not have a specific rule for stopping

Tags: c++, time-complexity

Here is a recursive function. Which traverses a map of strings(`multimap<string, string> graph`). Checks the `itr -> second` (s_tmp) if the `s_tmp` is equal to the desired string(`Exp`), prints it (`itr -> first`) and the function is executed for that `itr -> first`again.

```
string findOriginalExp(string Exp){
    cout<<"*****findOriginalExp Function*****"<<endl;
    for(auto itr=graph.begin();itr!=graph.end();itr++){
        string s_tmp = itr->second;
        string f_tmp = itr->first;
        string nll = "null";

        if(s_tmp.compare(Exp) == 0){
            if(f_tmp.compare(nll) == 0){
                cout<< Exp <<" :is original experience.";
                return Exp;
             }else{
                return findOriginalExp(itr->first);
             }
        } 
    }
}
```

There are no rules for stopping and it seems to be completely random. How is the time complexity of this function calculated?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229913/discussion-on-question-by-simsim-time-complexity-of-a-recursive-function-when-it).

Answer (score 2):

The thing is: Your function is not correct. Unless you have very particular preconditions on the contents of `graph` (which you didn't tell us) your code invokes undefined beahvior.

Maybe a compiler can convince you better than me. I added missing pieces to your code to get this:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

std::map<std::string,std::string> graph;

string findOriginalExp(string Exp){
    cout<<"*****findOriginalExp Function*****"<<endl;
    for(auto itr=graph.begin();itr!=graph.end();itr++){
        string s_tmp = itr->second;
        string f_tmp = itr->first;
        string nll = "null";

        if(s_tmp.compare(Exp) == 0){
            if(f_tmp.compare(nll) == 0){
                cout<< Exp <<" :is original experience.";
                return Exp;
             }else{
                return findOriginalExp(itr->first);
             }
        } 
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
}
```

And try to compile it with gcc `-Werror` [yields the following error](https://godbolt.org/z/6v1E6d):

```
<source>: In function 'std::string findOriginalExp(std::string)':
<source>:25:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
   25 | }
      | ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'std::string findOriginalExp(std::string)':
<source>:25:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
   25 | }
      | ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Not returning something from a function that is declared to return something is undefined behavior. In the presence of undefined behavior your code may appear to work, but it is still broken.

It is not meaningful to discuss time complexity of that function (unless you include preconditions that assure no undefined behavior is actually encountered to the considerations).

Comment: Will this problem be solved if I make an if condition for the map to check that it is empty before executing the function?

Comment: No, because there may be no element for which `s_tmp.compare(Exp) == 0` is true (btw, why not just `s_tmp == Exp`).

Comment: @simsim I strongly suggest you to use a debugger to see what actually happens in your code (unlikely that the compiler messes around trying to exploit the UB, because it would need to know the parameter to make any use of that)

Comment: @simsim try an example where `s_tmp.compare(Exp) == 0` is never `true`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 ok, I'm checking now with godbolt and correcting the code.

Comment: @simsim forecasting what might happen next: Please do not modify this question to ask for something else entirely (fixing the code will turn the question into something else). Instead I suggest you to open a new question, that can deal with complexity of hopefully correct code

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 ok, thank you for taking the time to explain. Based on the points you said, I will definitely correct the code and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to below code that I find more readable:

```
std::string findOriginalExp(std::string Exp)
{
    std::cout << "*****findOriginalExp Function*****" << std::endl;
    auto it = std::find_if(graph.begin(), graph.end(), [&](auto& p){ return p.second == Exp; });
    // assert(it != graph.end());
    if (it->first == "null") {
        std::cout << Exp << " :is original experience.";
        return Exp;
    }
    return findOriginalExp(it->first);
}
```

For complexity:

- You copy `Exp`: `O(M)`
- You do a linear search (with string) so `O(NxM)`,
- and a recursive call.

with

- `N`: size of graph
- `M`: max length of string.

Unless there is a infinite loop,
the deepest recursive call count would be the size of graph (you basically have a tree and trying to find root, so longest would be a list)

Result would then be `O(N²xM)`.

Comment: No, this code does not run properly in the program. It gets stuck inside a loop.

Comment: What is `graph`? does it contain pair of `std::string` or `const char*`? the latter is indeed problematic for by rewrite (`it->first == "null"` would lead false anytime).

Comment: graph is multimap. (`multimap<string,string> graph`).